# Storing a complex nested state

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have following requirements:

- Storing a complex deeply nested object
- Being able to change the order in a GET request across all nested elements

Tech:

- Java Spring
- JPA Hibernate
- Postgres

The json:

```
 [{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "test1",
    "children": [{
            "id": 2,
            "text": "test1"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "text": "test1",
            "children": [{
                    "id": 4,
                    "text": "test1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "text": "test1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Now I have two cases with this:

a) This nested state comes from the frontend and I want to have the exact same order again (unfortunately postgres or mysql are not necessarily giving out the same order you stored it)

b) I want the possibility to order by e.g. creationDate in this deeply nested state

I can not flatten the state within the frontend (e.g. with "parentId") because of performance reasons - flattening is recursive and very expensive.

Do you have an idea how to solve this task? Is postgres a good choice for that?

Comment: When you say postgres doesn't return the same order, do you mean postgres with json (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-json.html) or a relational model? With the relational mapping you are king and can use any order, just add an extra column for sorting (that you don't return to the front end). With json you should get back what you put in? As for sorting the json I would do that in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> Is postgres a good choice for that?

As terrible as any other relational database. I wouldn't be surprised if storing the entire structure as a string, parsing, and sorting it in code actually proved the most performant solution. If, however, you choose to map it onto a relational schema...

As far as saving goes, you'll obviously need a `@JoinColumn @OrderColumn @OneToMany` children list. I'd be wary of `@OrderColumn` as it could introduce serious performance issues.

As for retrieval, most dbs offer hierarchical query extensions, so you could try using a native query. See e.g. Oracle's https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm and the `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` clause. Postgres also allows for recursive queries, but the syntax is a bit more convoluted: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html.

Your app would need to reasemble the tree, but I'd still expect better performance than executing one query per each level to retrieve the hierarchy. Creating an index on `(id, parent_id)` would likely help. You can experiment with the native query approach vs `@OneToMany(fetch=EAGER)` to compare performance.